# Django web app not work on AWS, There is a ERROR=TemplateDoesNotExist and {% extends 'index2.html' %} not working

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My web app work on local server but it is not working on AWS.

```
1   {% extends 'index2.html' %}
2   
3   {% load static %}
4   
5   {% block title %} Who am I? {% endblock %}
6   {% block content %}
7   
8   
9   
10  <section class="space-sm  mt-3">
11      <div class="container">`
```

I am sorry it's my first question, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: you have to provide more information. do you get an error message? hoe did you deploy it on aws

Comment: This code can't possibly show us where you went wrong, the error suggests that it can't find the file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.